# How to use AWS to send time-sensitive updates to my Android app

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm basically just looking for a starting point here. I have an app which needs to include the ability to update certain data in real time.  For instance, the user has the ability to specify that she wants X to happen exactly 24 hours from the current time. I want to implement a framework for updating this end-user and any other relevant end-users after 24 hours that the event has occurred. Can anyone just provide me with a high-level explanation of which AWS services to implement and how to implement them in order to achieve this sort of framework? I think it includes some combination of SNS and SQS, but I'm not sure if these are relevant since I don't need to send a message or notification, rather more of an update that some sort of data has changed. If it's relevant, I'm currently using RDS with a MySQL database and Cognito for establishing user identities. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its most likely a combination of SNS, and an EC2 instance - plus your existing database (and optionally SQS).

SNS can take care of the 'push' notification to a mobile device, but you can't schedule things to happen   in the future (except for a few minutes).

Off the top of my head I would say the database keeps a list of what needs to be pushed, when it needs to be pushed and to whom.

The Ec2 instance has a cron job of some sort that polls on some in interval, running queries against your database to find 'things that need to be pushed now'.

If something needs to get a pushed, the cron job uses SNS to do the push - that could either just be a message (hey, you need to get new data), or else if the data is small enough, you could send the data within the message itself.

If you wanted to add a bit of scaling capability, the cron job that finds items to be pushed could, instead of sending out the SNS notifications itself, add a message to an SQS queue (i.e. work to be done), and you could use as many Ec2 instances as you needed querying the SQS queue and then sending out the SNS notifications in a parallel fashion.